# Suppress anchor tag <a> href when using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() 
  {
    $("#thang").load("http://www.yahoo.com");

    $(".SmoothLink").click( function()
    {
      $("#thang").fadeOut();

      $("#thang").load($(this).attr("href"));           

      $("#thang").fadeIn();

    });
  });

  </script>

  <a href="http://www.google.com" id="thelink" class="SmoothLink">click here</a><br /><br />
  <div style="border: 1px solid blue;" id="thang">
  </div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is a quick and easy way to ajax-ify a website by simply putting a class on certain links that I want to load up into a div.  The problem I am having is that the normal anchor action is being triggered and just redirecting to the link href normally.  How do I suppress the normal anchor action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    //prevent the 'following' behaviour of hyperlinks by preventing the default action
    e.preventDefault();

    //do stuff

});
```

or:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    //do stuff

    //equivalent to e.preventDefault AND e.stopPropagation()
    return false;
});
```

More information:

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29

Previous question on the difference between `return false` and `e.preventDefault()`:

[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: Don't you have to pass the e?

Comment: You need to add the `e` parameter to your first function definition, but other than that, light-speed and +1.

Comment: for the first one, shouldn't there be a var passed into the function called 'e'?

Comment: And it never hurts to pass the e out of habit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly related to your problem, but instead of doing this...

```
$("#thang").fadeOut();
$("#thang").load($(this).attr("href"));
$("#thang").fadeIn();
```

...jQuery is designed to let you chain methods, as such:

```
$("#thang").fadeOut().load($(this).attr("href")).fadeIn();
```